# Gigabyte Aorus X570 Xtreme RAM compatibility

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

On Gigabyte website these are the supported Corsair RAMs at 3600 MHz

[image]

But this one

```
Corsair DIMM 32 GB DDR4-3600 Kit, CMK32GX4M2D3600C18, Vengeance LPX
```

Is not listed. Does anyone know would this RAM work with that motherboard without any problems or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know would this RAM work with that motherboard without any problems

The `CMK32GX4M2D3600C18` DDR4 module kit is indeed compatible with your motherboard.

`CMK32GX4M2D3600C18` is simply a DDR4 kit that contains 2 16 GB DDR4 modules (`CMK16GX4M1A2400C14`).

If you really wanted you could purchase 2 individual 8 GB (`CMK32GX4M4B3600C18`) kits and it would perform exactly the same was as if you purchased a single `CMK16GX4M1A2400C14` kit.

`CMK16GX4M1A2400C14` is a 16 GB DDR4 module while `CMK32GX4M4B3600C18` is 8 GB modules.

The [specifications](https://www.aorus.com/X570-AORUS-XTREME-rev-10) for your motherboard specifically indicate it supports 16 GB DDR4 modules

> 4 x DDR4 DIMM sockets supporting up to 128 GB (32 GB single DIMM
>   capacity) of system memory

Comment: So the only difference is that this what I want to buy is 2x16 GB and on the compatibility list there is 4x8 GB... But why it's not listed there?

Comment: @lewis4u - The list in question does not contain a list of every single DDR4 module that exist.  Only those modules that were tested.

Comment: So if the module is not tested it doesn't mean that it won't work with the motherboard....

Comment: Correct, it will probably work, it just hasn't been explicitly tested.